# Path array is empty. Make sure to assign a valid path in the inspector. UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, game-development

Hello Unity community,

I'm currently facing an issue with my AICarScript in Unity, specifically with the `path` array being empty. I've implemented a waypoint-following system where the car should follow a path defined by child objects under a specified `pathGroup` in the inspector.

However, when I run the script, I encounter the following error message:

I've double-checked the following aspects:

1. **Inspector Assignment:** I have correctly assigned the `pathGroup` variable in the inspector to the GameObject containing the waypoints.
2. **Child Objects:** The waypoints are indeed child objects of the GameObject assigned to `pathGroup`.
3. **Hierarchy:** The waypoints are arranged in the correct hierarchy, with no additional unnecessary parent-child relationships.

I've added debug logs to the `GetPath` method to print the length of the `path` array and the names of the child objects. Strangely, the array length is 0, even though I expect it to be greater.

```cs
// GetPath method
void GetPath()
{
    Transform[] pathObjs = pathGroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    path = new Transform[pathObjs.Length - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < pathObjs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pathObjs[i] != pathGroup)
        {
            path[i - 1] = pathObjs[i];
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Path Length: " + path.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Waypoint " + i + ": " + path[i].name);
    }

    if (path.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Path array is empty. Make sure to assign a valid path in the inspector.");
    }
}

I'm seeking guidance on what might be causing the path array to remain empty during runtime. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or can someone offer insights into potential pitfalls related to this scenario?

Thank you for your time and assistance guys.
```

Comment: You can use debug mode on the inspector to see the values of private variables. Also check that the if statement inside the for loop is triggering.

Answer (score 2):

the only reason i can see here: pathObjs.length equals 1. I suggest you to check it out by adding an additional log message:

```
 Transform[] pathObjs = pathGroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
 Debug.Log($"child count: {pathObjs.Length}");
```

try this and make sure it's true.

Maybe waypoint object are disabled? you can use this to get disabled objects too.

```
pathGroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
```